# keychain: Warning: can't find gpg key; skipping

Tags: gnupg, keychain, gpg-agent

I'm trying to use `keychain(1)` with my GnuPG key on Debian Testing. However, I get the following message with this command:

```
$ keychain --agents gpg MYPGPKEY

 * keychain 2.8.2 ~ http://www.funtoo.org
 * Starting gpg-agent...
 * Warning: can't find MYPGPKEY; skipping
```

where `MYPGPKEY` is my actual key.

I can check that such key exits with the following command:

```
$ gpg --list-keys MYPGPKEY >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "key exists"
key exists
```

How can I add my gpg key with keychain?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it has been cross-posted to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41791930/keychain-warning-cant-find-gpg-key-skipping